# How do I format a date in Jinja2?

Tags: python, jinja2

Using Jinja2, how do I format a date field? I know in Python I can simply do this:

```
print(car.date_of_manufacture.strftime('%Y-%m-%d'))
```

But how do I format the date in Jinja2?

Answer (score 449, accepted):

There are two ways to do it. The direct approach would be to simply call (and print) the strftime() method in your template, for example

```
{{ car.date_of_manufacture.strftime('%Y-%m-%d') }}
```

Another, sightly better approach would be to define your own filter, e.g.:

```
from flask import Flask
import babel

app = Flask(__name__)

@app.template_filter()
def format_datetime(value, format='medium'):
    if format == 'full':
        format="EEEE, d. MMMM y 'at' HH:mm"
    elif format == 'medium':
        format="EE dd.MM.y HH:mm"
    return babel.dates.format_datetime(value, format)
```

(This filter is based on babel for reasons regarding i18n, but you can use strftime too). The advantage of the filter is, that you can write

```
{{ car.date_of_manufacture|format_datetime }}
{{ car.date_of_manufacture|format_datetime('full') }}
```

which looks nicer and is more maintainable. Another common filter is also the "timedelta" filter, which evaluates to something like "written 8 minutes ago". You can use `babel.dates.format_timedelta` for that, and register it as filter similar to the datetime example given here.

Comment: did you actually try that?  calling it directly results in: 'time.struct_time object' has no attribute 'strftime'

Comment: According to your question, you are talking about something different. Initial, this thread were about formatting a `datetime` object from the python module `datetime`, but you are trying to format a `struct_time` object from the low level `time` module. `struct_time` objects do not have a `strftime()` method, although there might be a global `strftime()` method in the time package. But I recommend you to use the high level (platform independent) `datetime` package instead.

Comment: Correct, I have been using time.time(), and should now consider whether I really want that, or datetime.datetime.today()  Thanks

Comment: I think you mean `babel.dates.format_datetime(value, format)`

Comment: defining a new filter, is not better in any way. More code to write = more code to be maintained = more code to be parsed, bit-cached (if used) and interpreted. One of the big advantages of using Jinja2 is the ability of writing small python code inside the template. Some of the performance gains, compared to Django's template system, comes from that.

Comment: @StefanNch "defining a new filter, is not better in any way". It can be: if the filter is called many times in the templates, this avoids repeating the format string, and can result into writting less code. And even more important, less *repeated* code, by adding an abstration.

Comment: Is it not possible to create a default rule so that I don't have to add |date to all my dates?

Comment: `{{ car.date_of_manufacture.strftime('%Y-%m-%d') }}` in the template directly is works perfetctly, thanks Man :)

Comment: I had to add ```app.jinja_env.filters['datetime'] = format_datetime``` .

Comment: "defining a new filter, is not better in any way" To add to @jacquev6 comment, sometimes you don’t have a choice. If the object you have access to from your template features the required method, you’re lucky. The answer did a good job showing how to add a filter for something that is not built-in (i18n using Babel).

Comment: @KarlP [`time.strftime`](https://docs.python.org/2/library/time.html#time.strftime) is the answer, e.g. `time.strftime('%c', time.localtime())`

Comment: Very nice solution. One tip however; avoid using python namespace. `format` is a built-in function.

Answer (score 33):

Here's the filter that I ended up using for strftime in Jinja2 and Flask

```
@app.template_filter('strftime')
def _jinja2_filter_datetime(date, fmt=None):
    date = dateutil.parser.parse(date)
    native = date.replace(tzinfo=None)
    format='%b %d, %Y'
    return native.strftime(format)
```

And then you use the filter like so:

```
{{car.date_of_manufacture|strftime}}
```

Comment: Why are `dateutil` and `native`?

Answer (score 23):

You can use it like this in template without any filters

```
{{ car.date_of_manufacture.strftime('%Y-%m-%d') }}
```

Comment: I got this error using his code: 

{{ '20220302'.strftime('%Y%m%d') }}

Error: 'str·object'·has·no·attribute·'strftime'

Comment: @ManojKumar seems like your variable is string this formatter expects that your variable is datetime object

Answer (score 19):

I think you have to write your own filter for that. It's actually the [example for custom filters in the documentation](https://jinja.palletsprojects.com/api/#writing-filters).

Answer (score 19):

If you are dealing with a lower level time object (I often just use integers), and don't want to write a custom filter for whatever reason, an approach I use is to pass the strftime function into the template as a variable, where it can be called where you need it.

For example:

```
import time
context={
    'now':int(time.time()),
    'strftime':time.strftime }  # Note there are no brackets () after strftime
                                # This means we are passing in a function, 
                                # not the result of a function.

self.response.write(jinja2.render_template('sometemplate.html', **context))
```

Which can then be used within `sometemplate.html`:

```
<html>
    <body>
        <p>The time is {{ strftime('%H:%M%:%S',now) }}, and 5 seconds ago it was {{ strftime('%H:%M%:%S',now-5) }}.
    </body>
</html>
```

Answer (score 7):

You can use it like this in jinja template
`{{ row.session_start_date_time.strftime('%d-%m-%Y %H:%M:%S')}}`

In this code the field name is `row.session_start_date_time`.

Answer (score 5):

Google App Engine users : If you're moving from Django to Jinja2, and looking to replace the date filter, note that the % formatting codes are different.

The strftime % codes are here: http://docs.python.org/2/library/datetime.html#strftime-and-strptime-behavior

Answer (score 2):

in flask, with babel, I like to do this :

```
@app.template_filter('dt')
def _jinja2_filter_datetime(date, fmt=None):
    if fmt:
        return date.strftime(fmt)
    else:
        return date.strftime(gettext('%%m/%%d/%%Y'))
```

used in the template with `{{mydatetimeobject|dt}}`

so no with babel you can specify your various format in messages.po like this for instance :

```
#: app/views.py:36
#, python-format
msgid "%%m/%%d/%%Y"
msgstr "%%d/%%m/%%Y"
```

Answer (score 0):

I use this filter, it's in Spanish but you may change the names as you need.

```
@app.template_filter('datetime')
def date_format(value):
    months = ('Enero','Febrero',"Marzo","Abril","Mayo","Junio","Julio","Agosto","Septiembre","Octubre","Noviembre","Diciembre")
    month = months[value.month-1]
    hora = str(value.hour).zfill(2)
    minutos = str(value.minute).zfill(2)
    return "{} de {} del {} a las {}:{}hs".format(value.day, month, value.year, hora, minutos)
```

Comment: you also could use this library: https://pypi.org/project/timeago/
it formats with "2 minutes ago" and similar in many languages

Answer (score -3):

There is a jinja2 extension you can use just need pip install (https://github.com/hackebrot/jinja2-time)