# How to use Jinja filter within a Flask application?

Tags: flask, jinja2

I am trying to follow this [solution](https://stackoverflow.com/a/4830620/92153), in order to create a datetime filter for my date values inside a template. The advantage of using babel would be the i18n.

I have inserted the code into a file called filter.py in my application package:

```
from f11_app import app
import babel

def format_datetime(value, format='medium'):
    if format == 'full':
        format="EEEE, d. MMMM y 'at' HH:mm"
    elif format == 'medium':
        format="EE dd.MM.y HH:mm"
    return babel.format_datetime(value, format)

app.jinja_env.filters['datetime'] = format_datetime
```

Now the error I get is:

```
File "/home/kave/projects/F11/Engineering/f11_app/templates/show_records.html", line 19, in block "body"

<td>{{ record.record_date|datetime }}

File "/home/kave/projects/F11/Engineering/f11_app/filters.py", line 9, in format_datetime

AttributeError: 'module' object has no attribute 'format_datetime'
```

In order to load the filters.py, the last line of my `f11_app`'s `__init__.py` is this:

```
from f11_app import views, filters
```

What could I be missing please?

Answer (score 10, accepted):

This because `babel` module didn't have `format_datetime` method. You must use `babel.dates.format_datetime` or `flask.ext.babel.format_datetime`. See: http://babel.edgewall.org/wiki/Documentation/0.9/dates.html and http://pythonhosted.org/Flask-Babel/#formatting-dates.

You also can add filter [with decorator](http://flask.pocoo.org/docs/templating/#registering-filters):

```
@app.template_filter('datetime')
def format_datetime(value, format='medium'):
    if format == 'full':
        format="EEEE, d. MMMM y 'at' HH:mm"
    elif format == 'medium':
        format="EE dd.MM.y HH:mm"
    return babel.format_datetime(value, format)
```

Comment: Yes, i was using the wrong namespace `import babel` instead of 'from babel.dates import format_date'  many thanks