# How to throw an error when a non-existent attribute is set with sqlalchemy declarative

Tags: python, sqlalchemy

For brevity I am just giving an example table and no other configuration.

```
class Widget(Base):
    id = Column(Integer, primary_key=True)


#Setup/config logic goes here.
# assume session object exists.

thing = Widget()
thing.foo = "bar"
#ideally throw atleast a warning that `foo` doesn't exist
session.add(thing)
```

Sqlalchemy will ignore `foo` being assigned to the record instance, I can understand why, but is there someway to catch these assignments?

Would I need to add my own `__init__` with some sort of **getattr** to implement a freeze/lock logic to the class or does sqlalchemy have something like this provided?

I caught a typo in my code where I meant to assign to a `net_amount` field and instead assigned to the non-existent `met_amount` and would like to somehow catch these bugs before they get to far out of control.

Comment: I would definitely provide custom logic in `__getattr__` function. There is also a possibility to define `__slots__` class variable which also can take care of such things, but I think SQLAlchemy internally make use of that so I would not risk.

Comment: @needtobe What little inspection I've done, it feels like getattr is the safer choice but even that might get complicated because of the extra attributes declarative adds to domain tables.

Comment: You probably don't want to override `__getattr__`: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/32334733/sqlalchemy-doesnt-seem-to-like-getattr.

Comment: You could possibly wrap `__getattr__` in a decorator that logs  the fact that it's been called or, inspects the instance and logs whether or not your attribute name is a column name.  I've never done this though, so testing required.