# How to render JSON on client-side from Google App Engine Entity

Tags: python, json, google-app-engine, jinja2

I would much appreciate some help on rendering a JSON object on client-side from a Google App Engine entity.

Here is all of my relevant code:

```
def render_str(template, **params):
   t = jinja_env.get_template(template)
   return t.render(params)

class BlogHandler(webapp2.RequestHandler):
   def write(self, *a, **kw):
      self.response.out.write(*a, **kw)

   def render_str(self, template, **params):
      params['user'] = self.user
      return render_str(template, **params)

   def render(self, template, **kw):
      self.write(self.render_str(template, **kw))

class Post(ndb.Model):
   subject = ndb.TextProperty(required = True)
   created = ndb.DateTimeProperty(auto_now_add = True)
   startdate = ndb.DateTimeProperty()
   enddate = ndb.DateTimeProperty()

class PostPage(BlogHandler):
    def get(self, post_id):
    key = ndb.Key('Post', int(post_id), parent=blog_key())
    post = key.get()
    postdict = post.to_dict()
    postdict['startdate'] = postdict['startdate'].isoformat()
    self.render("permalink.html", postdict = postdict)
```

In my script tag on the template page, I include

```
<script>
var jsonobject = JSON.parse({{ postdict['startdate']}});
var jsonobject1 = new Date(jsonobject);
</script>
```

Am I on the right track here? I would like to ultimately use the datetime object on the client-side for some Jquery functions.

Any help in pointing me in the right direction would be much appreciated.

Comment: what language are you writing in on the app engine side? and have you dumped the object on the web browser side? console.log(...) the playload?

Comment: Thanks a lot for reply. 

I'm using python on app engine side. I have not dumped the object on the web browser side. Could you advise me on how to do this?

Comment: Does this help?  http://stackoverflow.com/q/4830535/584846

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There are a number of problems with your code.  First of all, once you convert `post` to a dictionary `postdict`, you can't reference the elements with the dot notation.  You have to use a dictionary reference `postdict['startdate']` to reference the `startdate` element.

Next, I use the `isoformat()` function when storing a date in JSON format:

```
postdict['startdate'] = postdict['startdate'].isoformat()
```

This makes it easier to convert to a Javascript Date object:

```
<script>
var jsonobject = JSON.parse({{ postdict.jsonobject}});
jsonobject[0].y = new Date(jsonobject[0].y);
</script>
```

Comment: Thanks so much for the reply. I have the following code now:

`postdict = post.to_dict()`  
`x = postdict['startdate'].isoformat()`  
`y = [ {'y':x} ]`  
`jsonobject = json.dumps(y)`  
`postict['jsonobject'] = jsonobject`  

And in my script tag for this template, I have:  
`var jsonobject = JSON.parse( {{ postdict['jsonobject'] }} );`  
`jsonobject[0].y = new Date(jsonobject[0].y);`  

However, when I reference the variable jsonobject[0].y in a jQuery function, I get an error in the console that jsonobject is undefined and JSON.parse requires at least 1 parameter.

Comment: How are you rendering your template?  `template.render(postdict)`?

Comment: I use the following functions: `def write(self, *a, **kw): self.response.out.write(*a, **kw)`, `def render_str(self, template, **params):  return render_str(template, **params)` and `def render(self, template, **kw): self.write(self.render_str(template, **kw))`

Comment: Please update your question with all the code, including the call with `postdict`.

Comment: Thanks I've included all the code now. I very much appreciate your help. I'm new to programming and I'm having a hard time understanding how to get the datetime property for one my entities on the client-side so I can use it in jQuery functions.