# Flask jinja display date fields correctly

Tags: flask, jinja2, pymongo

I've found a shorthand method to fetch the results from MongoDb and to pass to the jinja template.

```
@app.route('/home')
def home():
    table = mongo.db.posts
    result = table.find( { } ).sort([("postdate", 1)])

    records = json.loads(json_util.dumps(result))
    if result.count() > 0:
        return render_template('users/index.html', posts=records)
    else:
        message = 'I couldn't find any post'
        return render_template('users/index.html', message=message)
```

And in *users/index.html* I would like to display the results like this:

```
{% for post in posts %}
<tr>
    <td>{{post._id}}</td>
    <td>{{post.title}}</td>
    <td>{{post.author}}</td>
    <td class="date">{{post.postdate}}</td>
</tr>
{% endfor %}
```

Everything works as expected except date fields. Is there a way to display date fields correctly ?

```
{'$date': 1508227970796}
{'$date': 1508228089163}
{'$date': 1508241780398}
```

Answer (score 0):

What you are seeing is the timestamp of this date, there are two possibilities to solve this issue:

you ca use this inside you view to convert the date into a readable format before sending the array to the Jinja template

```
from datetime import datetime
datetime.fromtimestamp(the_date_you_want_to_convert)
```

or you can create a [simple Jinja filter which](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4830535/python-how-do-i-format-a-date-in-jinja2) will convert a given timestamp into your readable date format.