# Boto3 python change date format

Tags: python, amazon-s3, boto3

I'm using boto3 and python to get information about objects in an S3 bucket. 
I' using boto as below:

```
context = super(s3, self).get_context_data(**kwargs)
    data = []
    aws = boto3.resource('s3')
    buckets = aws.buckets.all()
    #Get data from each bucket
    for bucket in buckets:
        bucketData = {}
        totalSize = 0
        bucketName = bucket.name
        fileBuckets = boto3.resource('s3').Bucket(bucketName)
        #Get data for each object inside each bucket
        for file in fileBuckets.objects.all():
            totalSize += file.size
        bucketData['bucketName'] = bucket.name
        bucketData['createdAt'] = bucket.creation_date
        bucketData['totalSize'] = file_size(totalSize)
        data.append(bucketData)
    context['buckets'] = data
    return context
```

And I display the creation date in the template like this:

```
<ul id='s3ItemDesc'>
        <li>{{ bucket.createdAt }}</li>
          <li>{{ bucket.totalSize }}/4GB</li>
        <li>
```

This is fine however I want to change the datetime stamp to just date. Currently I'm getting this:

```
Dec. 3, 2017, 2:11 p.m
```

But I would like to change it to display date only:

```
3/12/2017
```

I've been googling for a while but couldn't find anything. Any idea how this can be achieved?

Comment: Which template engine are you using? According to [docs](http://boto3.readthedocs.io/en/latest/reference/services/s3.html#S3.Bucket.creation_date) `bucket.creation_date` is a `datetime` object. So I think, the display style resp. string format is set by the template engine

Comment: I'm using Jinja

Comment: Try `{{ bucket.creation_date.strftime('%-d/%m/%Y') }}`

Comment: I get an invalid format string error.

Comment: Which OS are you working on? Does `.strftime('%d/%m/%Y')` or `.strftime('%m/%Y')` work?

Comment: I tested this `time = datetime.now` and then `d = datetime.strptime(str(time), '%Y-%m-%d %H:%M:%S')` but this didn't work neither.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Python: How do I format a date in Jinja2?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4830535/python-how-do-i-format-a-date-in-jinja2)

Comment: I think I was wrong. I'm just using plain django, no templating engine(at least I think so). I don't really understand the code in that thread.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Assuming you're using Django's template engine you can apply a filter to modify the date format as follows:

```
{{ bucket.creation_date|date:"d m Y" }}
```

For more information please refer to the docs about [`date` templating](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/dev/ref/templates/builtins/#date) and [`date` formatting](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/dev/ref/settings/#date-format).