# Using date filter in Jinja2 template raises TemplateSyntaxError

Tags: django, jinja2

I'm trying to format a datetime using Django built-in [date filter](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.8/ref/templates/builtins/#date). When I use
`{{ thread.added_at|date }}`, it works as expected and the date printed is similar to "Dec. 21, 2018".

But since I also want to format the date, I use the filter like this:

```
<span>{{ thread.added_at|date:"d m y" }}</span>
```

When I try to load the page, I get a TemplateSyntaxError:

> TemplateSyntaxError at /questions/
>   expected token 'end of print statement', got ':'

The website runs on Django 1.8.19. In [Django 1.8 documentation](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.8/ref/templates/builtins/#date), date filter appears to be able to be used like that. What is the problem in my template?

Comment: If you google `expected token 'end of print statement', got ':'` then the top results are for Jinja2, so it sounds like you are using Jinja2 templates instead of Django templates. [This question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4830535/python-how-do-i-format-a-date-in-jinja2) might help you.

Comment: @Alasdair seems like you are true, can you add it as an answer so I can accept it?

Comment: Glad that helped, I’ve closed the question as a duplicate