# How to convert a string to a datetime object inside a jinja2 template

Tags: jinja2, python-datetime

How do I convert a `string` to a `datetime` object inside of a `jinja2`  template?

I want to do something like the following, but strptime is not recognized.

```
{% set dtime=strptime(passedintime, '%H:%M:%S') %}
```

I have the `jinja2-time.TimeExtension` enabled in the environment. I have very limited ability to modify a string outside of the template. I basically only have access to the template itself.

Comment: this might help you https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4830535/how-do-i-format-a-date-in-jinja2

Comment: I read that prior to posting. Unfortunately I can't create a custom filter outside of the template.

Comment: ok. can you post `passedintime` value? a sample value is fine too

Comment: A string in roughly ISO8601 format e.g. '2021-06-02 16:04:09' although I can reformat the passed in as needed.

Comment: have you got the solution for this ?

Comment: Did you find a solution?