# Specify a default rendering method for a certain type in Jinja2

Tags: python, django, jinja2

In Jinja2, how would you specify a default rendering method for a certain type?

In particular, `datetime`?

I found it quite annoying when rendering datetime values from Django. They look like `2022-11-04T00:00:00.987654+00:00`. What was that `T` for, and why there was a plus `+` followed by `00:00`. My users who lived on small islands for their entire life wouldn't understand.
Aside from the formatting problem, Django gives UTC time objects. Always UTC, despite the `TIME_ZONE` in its settings module has been specified with a different value.

I know I can use a filter thing like [`me.time_of_death|format_datetime`](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4830535/how-do-i-format-a-date-in-jinja2). However putting it after every single datetime field sounds insane to me, and I don't want to be woken up in the midnight because of a datetime without that filter released on the previous day.

Is it possible to make it default?

Answer (score 0):

You can use dateparse:

```
from django.utils import dateparse
```

Then when before you pass the time to the template you can use the following to convert it to something more understandable to your fellow islanders:

```
readable_time = dateparse.parse_datetime(CONFUSING_TIME_STRING)
```